swagger is sometimes missing params in UI for NestJS API
I am using swagger to test and see detail of my API but sometimes it does not show the query params in one call but it shows in the other for instance this one. The post shows correctly but the get is missing both
@Get(':entityType/:entityId')
  @Permissions(ApplicationPermissions.hasApplicationAccess)
  async find(
    @Param('entityType', new ParseEntitTypePipe()) entityType: EntityTypes,
    @Param('entityId', ParseIntPipe) entityId: number
  ) {
    this.logger.verbose(
      `[GET] Find documents for entity type ${entityType} with id ${entityId}`,
      'DocumentsController'
    );
    return await this.documentsService.find(entityType, entityId);
  }

  @Post(':entityType/:entityId')
  @Permissions(ApplicationPermissions.hasApplicationAccess)
  @UseInterceptors(
    AnyFilesInterceptor({
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: storageLocation,
        filename: storageFilename
      })
    })
  )


Any pointer on where to look why these are missing

First, Create a Decorator Wrapper Function
import { SetMetadata, UseGuards, applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ParamGuard } from './param.protected.guard';

export function ParamValidation(dtoClass: any): MethodDecorator {
  return applyDecorators(
    SetMetadata('dtoClass', dtoClass),
    UseGuards(ParamGuard),
  );
}

Then Create a Guard Validator that will Validate your dto
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';

@Injectable()
export class ParamGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const handler = context.getHandler();
    const dtoClass = this.reflector.get('dtoClass', handler);
    if (!dtoClass) {
      console.log('DTO Class not found.');
      return false;
    }

    const { params } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const dtoInstance = plainToInstance(dtoClass, params);
    const errors = await validate(dtoInstance);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      // Your business logic for handling errors
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

This is the dto (Example)
export class EntityType {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(EntityTypeEnum)
  entityType: EntityTypeEnum;
}

This is Enum (Example)
  export enum EntityTypeEnum {
      HERO = 'HERO',
    }

Then you can use some how like this
  @ParamValidation(EntityType)
  @Get('/:entityType')
  getById(@Param('entityType') entityType: string): void {
    console.log('This is IncomingID: ', entityType);
  }

